# Simplest way to remove duplicates from an array, whilst still keeping the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What would be the most simple way to remove duplicates from an array that have a specific value the same, whilst still keeping the most recent one pushed in?

Let's say I have this function.

```
bucket.bucketList =[];

bucket.addItem = function(item) {
  bucket.bucketList.push(item);
}
```

The function pushes an object called foo this into the array on every mouse-scroll:

Some foo's also have a property ,

> foo.name = "something";

The question is, what is the best way to delete a duplicate based on their property name whilst keeping the most recents one pushed in?

**So the concept now is to remove all duplicates, except the last one, that have a `foo.name = "example".`**

**PS:** I am using jQuery already in my project, so if jQuery has a more elegant way of doing this than vanilla JS i'd be more than happy to use it.

**Edit:** This is my exact code snippet:

```
bucket.addItem = function(item) {
  bucket.bucketList.push(item);
  var dict = {}, item;
for (var i = bucket.bucketList.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    item = bucket.bucketList[i];
    if (item.name) {
        // if already in the dict, remove this array entry
        if (dict[item.name] === true) {
            bucket.bucketList.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            // add it to the dict
            dict[item.name] = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Unfortunately, the above function removes all duplicates from the array that have the same name property. What I want is just to remove duplicates that have a *SPECIFIC* property name. e.g : `item.name ="example"`

Comment: Do you need to use an array, specifically? If not, try using a map, instead, and just overwrite the value for the given key.

Comment: Yes for the time being I do, since I don't have the time to implement something else, of which I have no knowledge, but I will definetely look up what maps is later on.

Comment: Kryiakides, what are you actually trying to achieve with the code? If you are only using an array because you are not familiar with other data structures but basically just need the unique set of items and don't need them to be ordered, then a map would be the right data structure to use in this case.

Comment: *"but I will definetely look up what maps is later on"* Are basically already using a map, `dict[item.name]`. You just have to make it persistant between function calls. What *exactly* do you need the array for?

Comment: @FelixKling Hey, I just copied/pasted the code and added some spice over it, no need to go all Judge Judy on me :)

Comment: If you had that impression, I'm sorry. I just wanted to point out that you already almost using an an optimal solution.

Comment: @FelixKling Jeez, scrap the question - Thanks though I'm heading over to find out what maps are right away then

Comment: Most of the time, just simple objects are used as maps. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. Basically maps allow you to have a `name/key -> element` relationship, whereas arrays only allow `index -> element`. But because of that, the elements in a map/object are not ordered. If you need order, you have to use an array. You'll also hear the term "lookup table" instead of map or object.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks I'm already reading that, but in the meantime we should focus on the question anyway since more people might land on this question and be interested only for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bucket.addItem = function(item) {
    bucket.bucketList = bucket.bucketList.filter(function(e){
        return item.name !== "example" || e.name !== "example"
    });
    bucket.bucketList.push(item);
}
```

This basically removes all items that have the same name as the current item, then pushes the current item onto the list, but only if the name is `"example"`

Comment: That will do it, but will be very slow (time proportional to the size of the list). It might make sense to figure out what the OP is trying to do to see if there is a more performant alternative.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan  was hesitant to post my exact code since its too specific to help anyone else visiting this post, but I'll put it there now to make things more clear.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: I don't really see if there's a faster way to make sure there's no duplicates.
This only iterates the array once. _"very slow"_ is a overstatement, imo. That makes it sound like this script will have to run for a minute before it's done.

Comment: @Cerbus, there isn't a better way to do it given the strict requirements specified by the OP; however, understanding what the OP is really trying to accomplish may indicate a more performant alternative. Very slow is not an overstatement; the operation is O(n) and the OP was indicating that this would be executed on every mouse scroll (i.e. very frequently), depending on the size of n, that could easily make the scrolling janky (granted, it is not "very slow" by comparison to an O(n^2) or O(n^3) algorithm).

Comment: @Cerbrus What Michael says is unfortunately correct - performance is really a must - since the mouse scrolls also trigger other CPU consuming functions.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: Exactly how "CPU consuming" are we talking about? Also, how long does that array get on average use?

Comment: pretty small, but I'd like to know the faster way so I know what is best to use in the future. Doesn't mean that I won't upvote this though

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: _"Pretty small"_... Then I'd suggest you try this solution, and see if this has any performance impact at all.

Comment: @Where exactly do I declare which property name I want to target?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: You mean which property to check for duplicates on? In that case it's: `e.name !== item.name`. `e` is the item in the array it's checking, and `item` is the item you're trying to add.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52574/discussion-between-nicholas-kyriakides-and-cerbrus)

Comment: Just for the record: That chat in the previous comment actually has a discussion in it about filtering and accessing objects.

Comment: @Cerbrus It does but in the chat I again missed the point of what I was asking in the first place - I just want to remove dups, except the last one, only for items that have item.name ==="example" . I tried replacing the condition with {return e.name === "gridGroup"} to no avail